# Glob function in perl not working properly

Tags: perl

I am using `glob` function to capture a file in a directory using a wildcard and store it in a array. I am doing this on windows.
I am able to capture the correct file and then I need to mail it, but its capturing only the name and not the complete file, i.e. in mail I am getting nothing in the content of the file. Below is the snippet of my script. Please suggest where I am going wrong.

```
opendir(DAPATH,$sDAPATH) or die "Can't open $sDAPATH: $!"; 
print OUTLOG "\nfound da path : $sDAPATH\n"; 
my @adirs = readdir(DAPATH); 
print  OUTLOG "Starting capturing DA\n";
print  OUTLOG "checking if we have value of run id : $runVar\n";

my $pattern =  "*$runVar.csv";
print OUTLOG "$pattern\n";   
($pattern) = @_; 
@da =glob ("$sETLDAPATH/*$runVar.csv");
print  OUTLOG "da file : @da\n";
print  OUTLOG "Assigned DA\n";

closedir(DAPATH);
```

Comment: Your variable names are interesting...

Comment: `@da` only contains the file _names_. How are you trying to mail them? And where is `@da` from? (And what about the random indentation?)

You don't have to open and close directories to use a file glob.

Comment: i declared a simple array variable @da, if array is not the correct please suggest what variable should i use to collect the complete file, i ll use the same variable in mailing, i am using SMTP for mailing.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I used open and close directory since to collect the variable $runVar i was in other directory and then i moved to this directory to collect a file which contain that $runVar.csv  in its name.

Comment: It looks to me like your complete snippet could be replaced by `my @da = glob "$sETLDAPATH/$runVar.csv";` all the rest is not really needed.

Comment: @sur: Always use `use warnings` and `use strict` in your program.

Comment: @BenjaminW. warning nd strict are already added.  The extra things which you are seeing, i added them for simple testing so as to check till where code is running fine. That wont be a part of final script.

Comment: @serenesat i added a comment in your answer.Please check and help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [MIME::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MIME-Lite/lib/MIME/Lite.pm)  module to send email with attachment.

Example:

```
use MIME::Lite;

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From    => 'sur@example.com',
    To      => 'serenesat@example.com',
    Bcc     => 'test@example.com',
    Subject => "Use of MIME::Lite",
    Type    => "text/plain",
    );

$msg->attach(
    Type=> "TEXT",
    Path =>"/path/to/file",
    Filename =>"filename.txt",
    );

$msg->send;
```

---

`glob` gives full path of file. After that you need to read and slurp up the contents of file. For that you can use [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm)' `read_file` function:

```
Use File::Slurp::read_file;
# read in a whole file into a scalar
my $text = read_file( 'filename' );
```

---

If you are not able to install `File::Slurp` module, you can do it in this way:

```
foreach my $file (@da)
{
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

    my $text = do {
        local $/;
        <$fh>
        };

    close $fh;
}
```

Comment: it seems File::Slurp module is not installed on my server, do we have any other method other than glob and slurp to collect a file

Comment: What about `MIME::Lite` ?

Comment: my mailing part is working fine with SMTP, i am not sure wether MIME::Lite is also installed on the server or not but mailing is doing fine with SMTP. I am having problems only to collect the file as my original code is sending me only the name of the file and not the contents, also your provided solution of Slurp is not suitable for me, can you suggest any other alternative

Comment: Thanks serenesat, one quick question, for mailing can i use variable $file and that would send me the complete file(with content). Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: It seems $text is not getting its value in it:                                               my $text = do {
        local $/;
        <$fh>
        };
I tried to mail $text  and it said "use of uninitialized value $text"

Comment: please have a look at this and suggest

Comment: Try to print `$text` and see if you are getting anything or not. `my $text = do { local $/; <$fh> }; print "$text\n";`

Comment: i removed the for loop and the thing is working now, but now it is mailing me the content and the name of attachment is coming as the first line of the content, whereas i need the name of attachment as stored in array @da, i am working on that now, can you suggest me anything

Comment: First thing is code you have provided is not the right way to do the things. You can do it in better way. And other thing is I have already given you a good solution to send attachment by using module. If you want more help better to close this question and show us full code and tell us where you stuck by posting a new question.

Comment: FYI, [MIME::Lite isn't recommended by its maintainer](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT): "There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else."